# Extending a logical volume , stealing from others

Tags: centos, lvm, openstack, disk-volume

So I've been messing about with OpenStack and noticing that the cinder-volume which is created is only 20GB. I need to increase it ( or alteast I'm 99% certain i do :) )

Was looking around on the system

Currently this is the state of vgs

```
[root@openstack ~]# vgs
 VG               #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
 centos_openstack   3   3   0 wz--n-  5.46t  60.00m
 cinder-volumes     1   2   0 wz--n- 20.60g 612.00m
```

and here is the pyshical volumes themselves

```
[root@openstack ~]# pvs
  PV             VG               Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/loop1     cinder-volumes   lvm2 a--  20.60g 612.00m
  /dev/nvme0n1p3 centos_openstack lvm2 a--   1.82t  60.00m
  /dev/nvme1n1p1 centos_openstack lvm2 a--   1.82t      0
 /dev/nvme2n1p1 centos_openstack lvm2 a--   1.82t      0
```

And this is the overall filesystem.

```
[root@openstack ~]# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_openstack-root   50G   21G   30G  41% /
devtmpfs                           126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              126G  4.0K  126G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              126G  450M  126G   1% /run
tmpfs                              126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     497M  165M  332M  34% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0                         1.9G  6.1M  1.7G   1% /srv/node/swiftloopback
/dev/mapper/centos_openstack-home  5.5T   33M  5.5T   1% /home
tmpfs                               26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                               26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/0



    pvdisplay
      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p3
      VG Name               centos_openstack
      PV Size               1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              476756
      Free PE               15
      Allocated PE          476741
      PV UUID               80VCZq-TfYz-ys8B-TmMB-yJzc-3UCg-MUfHKR

      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/nvme1n1p1
      VG Name               centos_openstack
      PV Size               1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes (but full)
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              476931
      Free PE               0
      Allocated PE          476931
      PV UUID               ZmAIas-jPNP-bAFr-O5DA-0QTa-y7Jw-RlNAES

      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/nvme2n1p1
      VG Name               centos_openstack
      PV Size               1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes (but full)
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              476931
      Free PE               0
      Allocated PE          476931
      PV UUID               vhJ75z-5qoc-tPZM-vzWn-p5RU-vSYb-ADkfGG

      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/loop1
      VG Name               cinder-volumes
      PV Size               20.60 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              5273
      Free PE               153
      Allocated PE          5120
      PV UUID               nWurkY-Bwlv-YjMc-wYH5-yPi4-47x6-GVgJL2
```

So basically my end goal is to have the cinder-volumes with about 5T of space and leave the centos_openstack with the remaining half a TB.

I was looking online and I found this [guide](https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/openstack-increase-volume-capacity/) . But I'm basically I'm too afraid to kinda follow it ... Like not seeing /dev/loop1 as a mounted point on `df -h`  as well as not understanding why 5.5TB is in the centos_openstack mount and how to reduce that size to give it to cinder-volumes.

Anyway TL;DR --- I'm too scared to go about doing what I want to do , if anyone can help guide me towards my end goal ( making the cinder-volumes ~5TB in size ) I'd really appreciate it